# How do I select an element value from an Node List?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, nodelist, createtextnode

I need help in an exercise. I have to create a new element with a specific TextNode. This TextNode is the value from two inputs. FirstName and LastName  that creat a new paragraph with that values when I click the submit button. 
I tried do a lot of things without sucess. The result doesn't show.

This is the snippet code:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict'

    var $form = document.getElementById('form1');
    var $names = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var $button = document.getElementById('press');

    $button.addEventListener('click', getValueName);

    function getValueName() {
        for(var i = 0; i<$names.length; i++) { 
            $names[i]; 
        } 
    
        var output=document.createTextNode('$names.value[0]' +
        '$names.value[1]' ); 
        var novop=document.createElement('p');
        novop.appendChild(output); 
        $form.appendChild(novop); 
    }
})();
```

```html
<form id="form1" onsubmit="getFormvalue()">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <button id="press" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Put everything inside the for loop, step the loop by 2, and retrieve `$names.value[i]` and `$names.value[i + 1]` instead of fixed indices.

Comment: When you say everything inside the loop ,you are saying all the function **getValueName**? or the **var output** , only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is getting value from array of values

> names.value[0] + names.value[1]

while the array is of names

> names[0].value + names[1].value

```js
function getFormvalue() {

  var formData = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var names = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var output = document.createTextNode(names[0].value + names[1].value);
  var novop = document.createElement('p');
  novop.appendChild(output);
  formData.appendChild(novop);
}
```

```html
<body>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <button id="press" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getFormvalue()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Comment: What I think is interesting is you don´t need a loop  and you can do it : name[0] , name[1].amazing. Can you explain me why? I am new in javaScript so I am very interested to know the reason. thank you so much in advanced

Comment: The reason is because you already know that variable `names` stores exactly two items, that match with two inputs on your entire HTML form. So the `names[0]` references the first input, and `names[1]` to the second input. Array indexes starts at 0. If your form would had several inputs, the ideal solution would be with a `for` or another loop, because put all references to each indexes manually is a bad idea for maintenance purposes in the future, and so painful; just imagine that what happens if your form would had hundreds of inputs!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the original code is a little different, but try with this solution.

```js
function getFormvalue() {
    'use strict'

    var $form = document.getElementById('form1');
    var $names = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var $button = document.getElementById('press');

    var output=document.createTextNode("");
    for(var i = 0; i<$names.length; i++) { 
        output.textContent += $names[i].value; 
    } 
    
    var novop=document.createElement('p');
    novop.appendChild(output); 
    $form.appendChild(novop); 
    
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return getFormvalue();">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <button id="press" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you want the same result with less code, this is an ideal solution:

```js
function getFormvalue(){
  var $form = document.getElementById('form1');
  var $names = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  
  $form.innerHTML += "<p>" + $names[0].value + " " + $names[1].value + "</p>";
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return getFormvalue();">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <button id="press" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can learn more about [HTML DOM innerHTML Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)